# Jackrabbit Oak versioning Custom Node with Custom attributes

Tags: jcr, jackrabbit

Question is regarding versioning of node,

Step 1) If a Custom node which is of type mix:versionable and with custom properties is added as child of root node. using 
  Node node=rootNode.addNode(name, type);
  node.addMixin("mix:versionable");
  setFolderNodeAttributes(cutomMetadataObj, node, type);  api.

Step 2 ) and if second version is created and saved on same node but with Different attributes for eg. below

```
final VersionManager versionManager=session.getWorkspace().getVersionManager();
        Node node = RootNode.getNode(name);
        versionManager.checkout(node.getPath());
        setCustomNodeAttributes(newMetadataObj, node, type);
        session.save();
        versionManager.checkin(node.getPath());
```

Now Version history object gives me two version 
1) jcr:rootVersion
2) First Version naming 1.0

This version 1.0, has currently updated Custom attributes, and root version doesn't have any custom attributes.
So for first commit or 0the version of node, which was created in step 1, custom attributes are lost(In DB they are present), but through VersionManager API I'm not able to read the 0th commit attributes.

I'm using following code for iterating over versions

```
 final VersionHistory versionHistory = versionManager.getVersionHistory(node.getPath());  
    final VersionIterator versionItrator = versionHistory.getAllVersions();
    while(versionItrator.hasNext()){
    final Version version = versionItrator.nextVersion();
    final Node idNode = version.getFrozenNode();
if (idNode.hasProperty("<Custom Property>")){  
// For JCR:rootVersion its not present and for version 1.0 it printing latest checkedin property
}
}
```

Thanks In advance

Comment: Was the state of the node that you are missing ever checked in?

Comment: The state of node that is missing was created in following way

Comment: Well, if you truly believe something is broken I would recommend that you open a JIRA ticket for Oak and attach a reproducible test case.

Comment: Will try to figure out if anything missed from my side.

Comment: @JulianReschke Thanks. Will do.